# Serving offline html 5 mobile apps on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, xamarin

I am writing a mobile application that needs to be accessible offline (ideally without ever requiring connection to external webserver). The app is using the AngularJS framework for templating / data-binding.

The application services and data layer are written in Xamarin. The user interface will ideally be written using html5 / angularJs

As Angular does not work using file:/// urls, I am investigating the following options:

1. Offline application (serving files from external webserver) 
   a. using cache.manifest to ensure application works offline.
   b. Javascript bridge to get information from data layer.
2. Including a web server as part of the application to bridge the user interface and services.

Ideally I would like to go with solution 2 - as it means that the application can work in a fully offline mode.

Are there any issues with running a web server within an Android application? Can anyone recommend a .Net web server that can be incorporated in Xamarin - or a android .jar web server that can be integrated?

Comment: I am interested in the option one, did you do any progress on that?

Comment: Hey Alan were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the HTML and Javascript files directly on the `WebView` using a local `file://` URL. you don't need the web server.

Just add a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and [load a local file](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/load_local_content/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/LocalWebView">
</WebView>
```

```cs
using Android.Webkit;

SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

WebView localWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);

localWebView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/Home.html");
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing and it works for standard html/js apps. However, anularJS does some funky things to the url ... e.g. When it loads up the first view it changes the url from file:///android_asset/Content/Home.html to file:///android_asset/Content/Home.html#/

Comment: have you tried the default .NET web server container? The self hosted HTTP server? Would it be enough?

Comment: That will hopefully do the job...I wasn't aware that .net had a self hosted web server...I will give it a shot and see whether this works...will keep you posted.

Comment: I will try to garb a sample and post here.

Comment: This one has me stumped. I have looked at using both OWIN and Service Stack but have been unable to find the necessary source / Android mono dlls to get these working with Xamarin for Android.

Am now considering:

Comment: i) Rolling my own web server using HTTPListener or ii) Downloading the html resources on first load using HTML 5 app cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the self-hosted server and consume it's pages with a webview.

You can use the [NOWIN project](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin) to self-host. Download it [here](https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin/archive/master.zip)

Here is a sample of a simple self-hosted webserver responding on port 8080:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace OwinHostingSample
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new StartOptions
            {
                ServerFactory = "Nowin",
                Port = 8080
            };

            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running a http server on port 8080");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(c =>
            {
                var path = c.Request.Path.Value;
                if (path == "/")
                {
                    c.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    c.Response.Write("Hello World!");
                    return Task.Delay(0);
                }
                if (path.Contains(".."))
                {
                    // hackers ..
                    c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    return Task.Delay(0);
                }
                if (File.Exists(path.Substring(1)))
                {
                    c.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    c.Response.ContentType = path.EndsWith(".js") ? "application/javascript" : "text/html";
                    return c.Response.WriteAsync(File.ReadAllBytes(path.Substring(1)));
                }
                c.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                return Task.Delay(0);
            });
        }
    }
}
```